# MonogDB just showing connecting when I run command mongo

Tags: mongodb

Hey guys I am new to MongoDB. I have successfully installed and setup environment variables, I run command mongod its start. After that I run command mongo its run but its only showing in cmd like

**C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin>mongo

MongoDB shell version v3.6.3

connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017**

it is not getting connect only showing, connecting . Anyone here who can help me out?

Comment: how did you run `mongod`? Was it run successfully?

Comment: i am running command "mongod" or even tried "mongod.exe",yes it is running successfully

Answer (score 2):

Remove Your Installation and try this https://javabeat.net/monogodb-installation-windows/

Comment: facing same problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with ending the process from task manager. If not then try for once that may help. I was also getting this kind of issue and solved it when I ended all the running processes related to mongodb and run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

Did the prompt show again after you launch `mongod` ?

Comment: it is just showing waiting for connection on port 27017, but not showing prompt again.

Comment: It's weird, in your `mongod` console, it show that it accept connection and you don't have error log.

Comment: Try with MongoDB Compass if it can connect to mongo server

Comment: I have tried with Compass and with MongoBooster too, I am still unable to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you enabled authentication ? Can you show me your config file pls ?

Comment: Actually I am running it without config file.

Comment: Did you look at the log in your mongo directory ?

Comment: no Nicolas I am not using log or config file, I was using before but now I am directly running it. Is it necessary to use? It is showing all log in command prompt.

Comment: Usually no, but the log file is generated automatically when you launch mongod daemon, try to look in your c:\data or c:\data\db if it's here

Comment: Try with `mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1`

Comment: No there is no log file in c:\data\db or c:\data.

Comment: still getting same response :(

Comment: I really don't know what's the problem :/